# How to prevent data-deferred-load and force all data to load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, deferred, deferred-loading

I am trying to figure out a way to force a page to load all elements on the page without having any deferred loading.  This is the page in question:

http://v3.torontomls.net/Live/Pages/Public/Link.aspx?Key=145177a42bc64537b568ad2e71c157da&App=TREB

As you will see, there are a total of 31 records listed in the table at the top of the page, but when I look at the source code of the page I can see that there are 25 records which have the class `data-deferred-loaded` and 6 records which have the class `data-deferred-load`.

Here is a photo of what I am talking about:

[image]

I am trying to scrape the information from this page, but before I do that I need to ensure that all 31 of the records have loaded.  How can I force them all to load?

Comment: _As you will see.._ We can't see anything.

Comment: 500 - Internal server error.

Comment: Sorry about that.  I just corrected the link.

Comment: You're trying to scrape this external page in browser? Do you know it's impossible due to [Same-origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)?

Comment: Thanks @hindmost, but I dont understand why you say this is impossible.  If I can force all of the elements on the page to load, there should be nothing preventing me from saving whatever information has been loaded.

Comment: _I dont understand why you say this is impossible.._ You can do that in browser as its user, but you can't do the same by Javascript. Read the link I provided, it explains it in detail